# Laravel Different Database Credentials for local and production

Tags: database, laravel

I would like to know: How can I maintain different credentials for my database. Like when I am working locally, laravel should rely on Database A while after pushing it on my server it should rely on Database B?

Comment: Local setting set in .env file and server setting in database.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do like this
config/database.php (production setting)

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'db'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', '********'),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],
```

.env file (local setting)

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=project.dev

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=mydb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the better approach is to use different variable names for `local`, `staging` and `production` something like below (not tested).

`database.php`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

//... Other code

'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => (App::environment('local') ?
        env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1') : App::environment('production')) ?
        env('PROD_DB_HOST') : env('STAGING_DB_HOST'),
    'port' => (App::environment('local') ?
        env('DB_PORT', '3306') : App::environment('production')) ?
        env('PROD_DB_PORT') : env('STAGING_DB_PORT'),
    'database' => (App::environment('local') ?
        env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge') : App::environment('production')) ?
        env('PROD_DB_DATABASE') : env('STAGING_DB_DATABASE'),
    'username' => (App::environment('local') ?
        env('DB_USERNAME', 'root') : App::environment('production')) ?
        env('PROD_DB_USERNAME') : env('STAGING_DB_USERNAME'),
    'password' => (App::environment('local') ?
        env('DB_PASSWORD', 'localhost') : App::environment('production')) ?
        env('PROD_DB_PASSWORD') : env('STAGING_DB_PASSWORD'),
    //... other variables
],

//... other code
```

`.env`

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=localdb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=admin123

STAGING_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
STAGING_DB_PORT=3306
STAGING_DB_DATABASE=stagdb
STAGING_DB_USERNAME=staginguser
STAGING_DB_PASSWORD=stag123

PROD_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
PROD_DB_PORT=3306
PROD_DB_DATABASE=proddb
PROD_DB_USERNAME=produser
PROD_DB_PASSWORD=prod123
```

Answer (score 0):

use env and change accordingly.

Config::set('database.default', 'production-DB');
[Laravel Configs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/configuration)